# Store session to use it on webview IOS

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

Good day everyone . I'm currently facing a problem where in I don't have any idea how to store the session that the web API will give me and use that to get the data and put it on webview

Here's what i've got so far

```
let URL_USER_LOGIN = "https://xxxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx"

let parameters: Parameters=[
"username" : usernameTextField.text!,
"password" : passwordTextField.text!
]

Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString
{
response in
//WEBVIEW
//if success
let url = NSURL(string:"https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/dashboard")
 let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL) self.WebView_Dashboard.LoadRequest(requesObj)
}
```

I'm using `Alamofire` framework for the post request

Comment: you can get cookie and fetch sessionid from it than store it and where you want to fetch data with session you can use it this sessionid for that.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood. From one my old project: (Sorry for Objective C. It's easy to convert into Swift)

```
-(void)saveCookies:(NSString*)user_id{
    NSMutableArray *theCookies = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
        [theCookies addObject:cookie];
    }
    if (theCookies.count>0){
        NSData *cd = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theCookies];
        NSString *cookiesFilesPath = [appDelegate cookPathForUser:user_id]; // Here your path to file (or you can store it anywhere)
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:cookiesFilesPath contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];
        [cd writeToFile:cookiesFilesPath atomically:YES];
    }    
}

-(NSArray*)cookiesForUser:(NSString*)user_id{
    NSData *cookiesData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[appDelegate cookPathForUser:user_id]];
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookiesData];
    return cookies;
}

-(void)resetCookies {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
} 

- (void)applyCookies:(NSArray*)cookies {
    for (int i = 0; i<cookies.count; i++){
      NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [cookies objectAtIndex:i];
      [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
    }
} 

- (void)addCookies:(NSArray *)cookies forRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
    if ([cookies count] > 0)
    {
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSString *cookieHeader = nil;
        for (cookie in cookies)
        {
            if (!cookieHeader)
            {
                cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@",[cookie name],[cookie value]];
            }
            else
            {
                cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@; %@=%@",cookieHeader,[cookie name],[cookie value]];
            }
        }
        if (cookieHeader)
        {
            [request setValue:cookieHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
        }
    }
}
```